# ifelse within a a loop with vectors in R

Tags: r

I have a data set that looks like

```
    V1 V2   V3
1  Yes  1    a
2  no   2    a
3  Yes  3 NULL
4  no   4    a
5  Yes  1    a
6  no   2 NULL
7  Yes  3    a
8  no   4    a
9  Yes  1 NULL
10 no   2    a
11 Yes  3    a
12 no   4 NULL
13 Yes  1    a
14 no   2    a
15 Yes  3    a
16 no   1 NULL
17 Yes  2    a
```

I then two sets of vectors

```
values=c('Yes',3)
columns=c(1,2)
```

I want to check to does column 1 equal yes and column 2 equal 3. I used this code

```
f=ifelse(data[,columns[1]]==values[1] & data[,columns[2]]==values[2] ,1,0)
```

This worked perfectly but I want code that will loop through vectors of size n, n values and n columns.

I tried

```
flagf=apply(data, 1, function(x) {ifelse(all(data[,columns[1:length(columns)]==values[1:length(values])),0,1)})
```

and

```
ifelse(data[,columns[1:length(columns)]==values[1:length(values)],0,1)
```

Both did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Without having completely understood what your condition is, I suggest you using `dplyr` in combination with `ifelse`.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- read.table("clipboard", header=T) # reading your data...
df %>%
  mutate(cond = ifelse(V1=="Yes" & V2==3, TRUE, FALSE))
    V1 V2   V3  cond
1  Yes  1    a FALSE
2   no  2    a FALSE
3  Yes  3 NULL  TRUE
4   no  4    a FALSE
5  Yes  1    a FALSE
6   no  2 NULL FALSE
7  Yes  3    a  TRUE
8   no  4    a FALSE
9  Yes  1 NULL FALSE
10  no  2    a FALSE
11 Yes  3    a  TRUE
12  no  4 NULL FALSE
13 Yes  1    a FALSE
14  no  2    a FALSE
15 Yes  3    a  TRUE
16  no  1 NULL FALSE
17 Yes  2    a FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I extend this to n conditions so I don't have to write and & between each of the conditions.

Comment: I believe that depends on your conditions. Are they somehow alike?

Comment: So for example if I also wanted to specify that the third column had to be 'a'.

Comment: As to my knowledge you will need an & operator between every different condition. R cannot know what your condition is, so you have to tell. What do you want to do with the information in cond, anyway?

Comment: I want to check do certain columns have a set of certain value.